# Ending Python if-then using triple double quote gives EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, arcmap, field-calculator, syntaxerror

I keep getting the same error, I think it's because of how I end my if-then statement. It basically looks like this, except it's much longer (like, 300 lines long).

```
myIfThenVariable="""def myIfThen(field, fieldB):
   if field=="Thing One":
      return "T1"
   elif field=="Thing Two":
      return "T2"
   elif field=="Something else":
      return fieldB
   else:
      return field """"
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (MyRhubarb.py, line 374)
```

- I have my if-then book-ended with triple quotes.
- I tried adding a backslash after the word field ( `field\"""`).
- I copied and pasted the same code into the field calculator in ArcMap and was able to run it without issue.

Comment: You have 4 quotes at the end instead of 3

Comment: Why are you wrapping a function in quotes and assigning it to a variable?

Comment: Even though you mention using this with ArcMap's Field Calculator (or presumably its CalculateField function in a script) the code and error is pure Python and is better researched at [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of ending with three quotes, you have four.  Technically this is closing the triple-quoted string and starting a new one, and since there is no closing for the new one you get the `EOL` error.

Comment: I probably need to turn-in my python card and go find a different job. Thanks for noticing what I failed to see despite hours of trying. What is wrong with my eyeballs?